# GCM call method if app is running

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, google-cloud-messaging

I have an Application structured this way :

> Activity A: Login Activity B: ListView

I configured the GCM and everything's alright. But now I want to start Activity A only if App is not running and if the app is running I want to call the method in Activity B which refreshes the ListView in Activity B. How can I find out if the App or the Activity B is running?

Thanks.

Comment: BroadcastReciver ... one "created"/registered in manifest (aka always registered ) second one created and registered inside Activity B (and unregistered onPause of this activity) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok you can simply do it with sharedPreferences

when your app is running in your onCreate method call this method :

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit().putBoolean("running",true).apply();
```

on your onStop or onDestroy method when your app get destroyed

call this one

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity()).edit().putBoolean("running",false).apply();
```

now you can check if your app is running which means if running variable is true or false this way :

```
boolean run = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getBoolean("running",false);
```

EDIT

SERVICE for checking SharedPrefs Value

```
public class CheckService extends Service {

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    //TODO do something useful
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    //TODO for communication return IBinder implementation
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
boolean run = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getBoolean("running",false);
 if(run) {
// do what you want if the app is running
//run actualize in your case
 }
else {
//do whatever you want again if it's not
 }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.i(TAG, "Service destroying");
}
```

}

Comment: I guess the term not running is open to interpretation accoring to the OP but I bet he means when the app is not in the foreground. in that case onDestroy does not get called right away and will be called at a later time. So if app not in foreground means not running then it wont work

Comment: @tyczj but he can use the onStop method then

Comment: he could but he would have to put it in all his activities because onStop gets called when you navigate away from an activity ex. one activity to another, app is still running but not according to shared preferences if you use onStop in just one activity. Not saying you are wrong I am just providing more information so the OP is aware of possible problems

Comment: That's a really good idea and I think it works. In Activity A I added in OnCreate a Boolean True Value for Activity A and in Activity B I added in OnCreate a Boolean True Value for Activity B, so I can see if Activity A or B is running or both not running (In Both onDestroy I added False Value because when B starts, A gets destroyed. Great Idea! But the GCM creates a Notification with a PendingIntent. How can I make the action of the Notification depending on the SharedPreferences? Something like an OnClickListener....
'

Comment: Edited with explanation for PendingIntent

Comment: Sry I don't understand your answer :(

Comment: what is the exact thing you want ?

Comment: Yeah your right, I have to create an Activity or an Service which looks for the sharedpreferences. Great! Can I start a method in Activity B from this Service/choiceActivity? Because if Activity B is running I have to start the "actualize" method.

Comment: My problem is: I have in Activity B an AsyncTask which actualize the ListView. How can I start this AsyncTask from the Service? If Activity B is running I want to call the actualize AsyncTask Method.

Comment: simply put your AsyncTask inside of your service

Comment: Got it! I added a LocalBroadcastReceiver when receiving a message the receiver starts the actualize method in Activity B. Thanks for everything!!!!